# Validacion Livewire required_if

Tags: laravel, validación, laravel-livewire

tengo un problema y le he buscado, pero no encuentro me valide correctamente, mi problema radica fundamentalmente que el campo "asociado" y "motAnula" solo son Obligatorios si afip_cbte_id<>1 y afip_cbte_id<>86 en otros casos de  afip_cbte_id no son obligatorios.
he tratado con don if, pero nada toma solo primero, Gracias

Mi regla

```
          $rules = [
                'sale.client_id' => 'required',
                'sale.fecha' => 'required|date',                 
                'sale.afip_cbte_id' => 'required',
                'sale.concepto' => 'required',                 
                'sale.fservd'  =>'required_if:sale.concepto,>,1',
                'sale.fservh'  =>'required_if:sale.concepto,>,1',
                'sale.fvctop' =>'required',   
                'sale.asociado' =>'required_if:sale.afip_cbte_id,<>,1',
                'sale.motAnula' =>'required_if:sale.afip_cbte_id,<>,1',
            ];
```

Mi Modelo:

```
    protected $fillable = [ 
        'afip_cbte_id',
        'certificacion_id',
        'pto_vta',
        'numero',
        'client_id',
        'fecha',
        'fservd',
        'fservd',
        'fvctop',
        'hour',
        'subtotal',
        'iva',
        'total',
        'saldo',
        'cae',
        'fcae',
        'qrcode',
        'filename',
        'filefinal',
        'motAnula', //Motivo anulacion Rechazo, Equivocacion
        'asociado', // para notas de debito / credito
        'usr',
        'status',//0 Confeccionada 
       ];

    protected $casts = [
        'fecha' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
        'fservd' => 'datetime:d-m-Y', 
        'fservh' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
        'fvctop' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
        'fcae' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',

    ];
    public function Client(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Client");
    }
    public function AfipCbte(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\AfipCbte");
    }
    public function SaleDetail(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\SaleDetail");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar con [`Rule::requiredIf`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if):

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

// Si "sale.afip_cbte_id" no es ni 1 ni 86
$isRequired = ! in_array(request()->input('sale.afip_cbte_id'), [1, 86]);

$rules = [
    ...
    'sale.asociado' => Rule::requiredIf($isRequired),
    'sale.motAnula' => Rule::requiredIf($isRequired),
];
```

Por otro lado, fijate que a `required_if` tenés que pasarle un *campo* y un *valor* pero no un *operador*. Ésto es incorrecto `'required_if:sale.concepto,>,1'`. Tendrías que reemplazar esos `required_if` por `Rule::requiredIf()` y amar tu lógica ahí adentro:

```
Rule::requiredIf(request()->input('sale.concepto') > 1)
```

Estoy usando el helper `request()` porque no se si tus reglas las tenés definidas dentro de un *FormRequest* o dónde.

Comment: Muchas gracias @azeós